# Blazor Component with N nested item templates without data binding

Tags: razor, blazor

I have a blazor component which binds to a collection of objects to render a list of cards. This works great as it is.

What I would like to enable is to declaratively define the list of cards as razor syntax. Something like the following:

```
<MyListComponent>
   <Card>1st Card - Card-specific contents here</Card>
   <Card>2nd Card - Card-specific contents here</Card>
   <Card>3rd Card - Card-specific contents here</Card>
</MyListComponent>
```

**Can this be achieved?**

Note that i have created a datagrid/listview component which use RenderFragment "templates" for the Columns and Rows. But seems like this is different from what i am trying to achieve here.